# Socket.io join() doing nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I seem to be having a problem joining rooms in socket.io.
The socket.join() seems to be doing nothing. Here's my server side code

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('connected');
socket.on('joinRoom', function (data) {
    console.log("Joining room")
    socket.join("room1",function(){
        console.log("Joined room")
    })
    socket.to('room1').emit('roomJoined', 'SERVER',' has connected to this room');
});

socket.on('acknowledge', function (data) {
    console.log(socket.room)
});
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
   console.log("disconnected")
  });
});
```

I can confirm that the "joinRoom" event is fired as i can see "Joining room" in my console but "joined room" is not printed. Also on the client side "roomJoined" event is not fired. If I change

```
socket.to('room1').emit('roomJoined', 'SERVER',' has connected to this room');
```

to

```
socket.emit('roomJoined', 'SERVER',' has connected to this room');
```

then the client fires the roomJoined event which proves that the socket is not joining the room.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all... what version of Socket.IO are you using?

Comment: `socket.to('room1').emit('roomJoined', 'SERVER',' has connected to this room');` runs BEFORE the `.join()` has actually  completed so you won't see the `roomJoined` message in the client that just requested to join.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's not true if he's using Socket.IO 3.0. See [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes).

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes - As is common with socket.io, the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-join-room-callback) is apparently lacking in that regard as there is no mention of that change at all in the doc.  I thought this was an asynchronous operation because of the times when the adapter might involve database access (such as with the clustered redis adapter).

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes - Wow, they broke/changed a lot of APIs in 3.0.  Once again, they will render mass confusion on lots of development sites that had socket.io code examples.  And, we'll see lots of confusion on that topic here too.  If that API no longer accepts a callback, then why doesn't it throw an error if the OP is actually using 3.0 and passing a callback?

Comment: Apparently [Socket.IO doesn't care](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.ts#L244) that there's extra function arguments... You know how JS works.

Comment: im using socket.IO 3.0. @Take-Some-Bytes thanks for the docs. I realize why the "Joined room" is not logged but if join() is synchronous in v 3.0 why is the roomJoined event not fired on the client side?

Comment: i tried using await with socket.join() as well but that didn't work too

Comment: Nvm i had to use io.to() instead of socket.to() , thanks for he help though

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes - Yeah, I know how JS works, but if you were removing an important argument from a new version of an API, it sure would help people to fix their programming errors if you checked for passing something that is no longer supported and throw an error.  But, I don't know why I would ever expect that - the socket.io code base has never been friendly in this way and the doc has not been much help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already found your working solution, I'll explain why...

As talked about in the comments, in Socket.IO 3.0 the `socket.join` method is synchronous, and does not accept a callback. As for why your client isn't receiving the "joinedRoom" event...

Well, in all versions of Socket.IO, `socket.to` and `socket.in` does ***not*** send anything to the socket you're calling `socket.to` (or `socket.in`), as mentioned [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-to-room).

Comment: Thanks a lot TSB.. I accidently upgraded the socket.io and socket.io-client libraries from 2.3 to 4.0 and I had the callback for socket.join() method.. For many days I wasn't able to figure out the reason. And then I downgraded the libraries to 2.3 and everything is working fine now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I found the error which was using socket.to() instead of io.to() .
Changing

```
socket.to('room1').emit('roomJoined', 'SERVER',' has connected to this room');
```

to

```
io.to('room1').emit('roomJoined', 'SERVER',' has connected to this room');
```

worked for me.